# In SqlAlchemy, how to ignore m2m relationship attributes when merge?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

There is a m2m relation in my models,  User and Role.

I want to merge a role, but i DO NOT want this merge has any effect on user and role relation-ship.  Unfortunately, for some complicate reason, role.users if not empty.

I tried to set role.users = None, but SA complains None is not a list.

At this moment, I use sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.del_attribute, but I don't know if it's provided for this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd better fix your code to avoid setting `role.users` for the item you are going to merge. But there is another way - setting `cascade='none'` for this relation. Then you lose an ability to save relationship from `Role` side, you'll have to save `User` with `roles` attribute set.